# css positioning 2 divs in a div

Tags: css, html, positioning

i have a main div has 100% width, and 2 divs in it. one has 200px width and other will be 100%-200px, i mean;

```
  -----------------this is main div -------------
 |                                               |
 | ----subdiv1---- -------------subdiv2----------|
 ||              | |                            ||
 | --------------   ---------------------------- |
 |-----------------------------------------------|
```

subdiv1 has 200 px, subdiv2's width will be rest of empty space. I search on google but couldnt find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possible solution I hacked up using a `float: left` rule for the left-most div, and a `margin-left` rule for the right div: http://jsfiddle.net/P4xMj/

Example HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        Some content here
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        Some more content goes over here on the right. Let's make this
        content really long to see what happens when we wrap more than
        one or two line's worth. Extra text to fill the void.
    </div>
</div>
```

Example CSS (the background colors are just for visibility):

```
#container {
    background: #FF0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#left {
    background: #0F0;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#right {
    background: #F00;
    margin-left: 210px;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. Make sure to mark an answer as accepted, so future internet visitors will know it helped you. It will also help you boost your acceptance rating.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to add `float:left;` to your `subdiv1`.  Here is a few lines of code that will produce what you have shown.

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left;width:200px;background:#0F0">
  SUBDIV1
  </div>
  <div style="background:#F00;">
  SUBDIV2
  </div>
</div>
```

In short, use `float:left;` on your `subdiv1`

Answer (score 0):

You can `float: left` the left `div`, and have `margin-left: 200px` on the right `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/SpxH9/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#right {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

There's another technique you can use, which is to replace `margin-left` [with `overflow: hidden`](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats). This is useful because you don't have to have the dimension in there twice, and it adapts to changes more easily.

For example, with `10px` borders: http://jsfiddle.net/SpxH9/1/

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#right {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you try to do the same thing with the first technique I mentioned, you'll find that you have to manually calculate stuff: http://jsfiddle.net/SpxH9/2/ (and fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/SpxH9/3/)

Lastly, `overflow: hidden` on `#container` is used to contain the floats. You might wish to use [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) instead.